# Show that $X-Y = X \cap \overline{Y} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Very basic problem, just wanted to be sure I did this correctly.
The problem is "Show that $X-Y = X \cap \overline{Y}  $". There was hint in the problem telling one to let our universe $U=X \cup Y$. Here's my work:

**Notation:** $\overline{A}$ is the complement of a set, $A$, and the operator $-$ is meant to be a set difference, so that give two sets, $A,B$ we have $A-B=\{x\in A : x\not\in B\}$.

> $$X \cap \overline{Y} = X \cap [(X\cup Y)-Y]$$
>   $$=X \cap [(X-Y)\cup(Y-Y)]$$
>   $$=X \cap [(X-Y) \cup \emptyset]$$
>   $$=X \cap (X-Y)$$
>   $$=X-Y$$
>   $$\implies X \cap \overline{Y}=X-Y$$
>
> **Q.E.D**

I think I got it. It seemed really trivial, considering the whole "let $U=X \cup Y$" bit. Just wanted to be sure I didn't overlook anything

Comment: What's the bar over in this context mean?

Comment: Can you define your terminology? Is the $-$ supposed to be a set difference or a translate? Your notation $\overline{Y}$ usually means "closure" but I think you want $Y^c$, the complement of $Y$.

Comment: @Nameless I'm almost certain he means that to be the set difference, what I would write:  $X\setminus Y$.

Comment: Sorry when I first began seeing set theory from another book, $\overline Y$ denoted a complement. I did indeed mean $Y^c$, now realizing that that is standard notation

Comment: @user146925 your proof looks OK, assuming the edits I made to clarify notation are correct.

Comment: Alright cool! Thank you. Also, another thank you for helping me realize the standard notation. I've gotten accustomed to $X-Y$ denoting set difference and $\overline{Y}$ denote set complement.

Comment: I think "$-$" for relative complement isn't *too* out there:  I've seen it in some places. I think $\setminus$ has become much more popular because when you have sets in more complicated objects that notation can be more useful for other things, but $\overline{A}$ for the complement is very uncommon in my experience.

Comment: It's hard to judge whether this proof is correct without knowing how the operations are defined in the specific text.  In many texts, the relative difference $X-Y$ is **defined** to be $X \cap \bar{Y}$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove set equality one needs to show that each set is a subset of the other. That is, 
$$A=B \, \, \iff\left(A\subseteq B\right)\, \land \left(B\subseteq A\right)$$

So, to prove problem presented we need to show $X \cap Y^{c} \subseteq X\setminus Y$ and $X\setminus Y \subseteq X \cap Y^{c}$

*Proof:*
Part 1: $X \cap Y^{c} \subseteq X\setminus Y$
Assume: $x \in X \cap Y^{c} \quad$ Show: $x \in X\setminus Y$
So by definition of set intersection, $x \in X$ and $x \in Y^{c}$
Set complement is defined as $Y^{c} = U \setminus Y$, so $x \in U$ and $x \notin Y$, where $U$ is defined to be our universe.
So, $x \in X$ and $x \notin Y$
So by the definition of set difference, $x \in X\setminus Y$

Part 2: $X\setminus Y \subseteq X \cap Y^{c}$
Assume: $x \in X\setminus Y \quad$ Show: $x \in X \cap Y^{c}$
So by the definition of set difference, $x \in X$ and $x \notin Y$
Trivially (assuming well-defined sets), $x \in U$, where $U$ is our universe.
So, $x \in U$ and $x \notin Y$, which by the definition of set difference implies $x \in U \setminus Y$
Set compliment is defined as $Y^{c} = U \setminus Y$, where $U$ is defined to be our universe.
Therefore, since $x \in U \setminus Y$, $\, \, x \in Y^{c}$
Since $x \in X$ and $x \in Y^{c}$ and by the definition of set intersection, $x \in X \cap Y^{c}$
$\Box$